# Can you Multi Attack with Operative Trick Attack?

Tags: starfinder

Apparently you are allowed up to two attacks in single turn in Starfinder, albeit at a -4 penalty to both attacks as a full action. Trick Attack, Starfinder's variant of Sneak Attack, is also now a full action that requires an opposed skill check. Can you then mechanically Multi Attack with a Trick Attack and still follow standard rules like first attack that hits deals the precision damage?

Answer (score 10):

No, you cannot. As explained on p93, Trick Attack is a special kind of Full Action that allows you to move, and then make an attack. A Full Attack is a distinct type of Full Action, as outlined on p248. You can only take a single Full Action during your turn, so these two actions are mutually exclusive.